# How to display only 1 item in C# google org chart?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, google-chart

I have created the following chart using google organisation chart but I have some problems. When I open the page or when I refresh the page it shows up the full chart like in picture below. But I want only the items that are in red square to be shown how can I do this.

I do not want to get a few items from the list but when I open the page it shows the whole chart with its all list item and instead when it opens I want to display only 5 items and let user to expand others do you understand me?

This is the picture of chart how it looks like and how I want it to be!

[image]

And here is my full c# code:

```
namespace OrganizationChartUsingGoogleAPI.OrganizationChart
{
public static class ConvertTo
{
/// <summary>
/// Convert the object type in the given type and handle the DBNULL.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type to convert</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">value</param>
/// <returns>converted value and if DBNULL then return the type's default value i.e. string = string.Empty, Int16=0 </returns>
public static T CastIn<T>(this object value) where T : IConvertible
{
    if (value == DBNull.Value)
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(string.Empty, typeof(T));
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }


    if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Convert.ToInt32(value), typeof(T));

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
 }
}

public partial class OrganizationChartUserControl : UserControl
{
//Get the List name to fetch the data from
string listName = "OrgChart_Demo";
int iRowCounter = 0;
string sAllNewRows = string.Empty;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Fetch the data (recursively) from the list
    GetNode(string.Empty);

    //Generate the Client Script and Register
    GenerateClientScript(sAllNewRows);
}

private void GenerateClientScript(string sAllNewRows)
{
    string csName1 = "OrgChartScript";
    Type csType = this.GetType();

    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered. 
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(csType, csName1))
    {
        StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
        cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript'    src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>");
        cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");


        cstext.Append("google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });");

        cstext.Append("google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);");

        cstext.Append("function drawChart() {");
        cstext.Append("var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();");

        cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Name');");                
        cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');");
        cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');");

        cstext.Append("var rowArr = new Array();");

       cstext.Append(sAllNewRows);

        cstext.Append("data.addRows(rowArr);");

        cstext.Append("var chart = new  google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
        cstext.Append("chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true, allowCollapse: true });");
        cstext.Append("}");
        cstext.Append("</script>");
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName1, cstext.ToString(), false);

    }

}

private void GetNode(string reportsTo)
{
    SPListItemCollection itemCol = GetListItems(listName, reportsTo);

    foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
    {
        //create a new row
        sAllNewRows += createNewRow(item);

        //Recursion
        GetNode(item["Name"].ToString());
    }

}

private string createNewRow(SPListItem listItem)
{

    //Converting list items to strings.
    string sName = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Name"]);
    string sTitle = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Title"]);
    string sMoreInfo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["MoreInfo"]);
    string sReportsTo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["ReportsTo"]);

    //Checking if image field ref is empty or null (if it does't provide any img source link!)
    ImageFieldValue pageImage = listItem["Pageimage"] as ImageFieldValue;
    string sPicture = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageImage.ImageUrl) ? "#" : pageImage.ImageUrl;


    StringBuilder sText = new StringBuilder();
    sText.Append("var NewRow = new Array();");

    //this row shows the image and everything else what chart needs
    sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '{0}', f: '<img src =\"{1}\" style=\"width:57px; height:57px; float:left;\" />{2}<div style=\"color:white; font-style:Arial\">{3}</div>' }});", sName, sPicture, sName, sTitle));

    sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sReportsTo));
    sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sMoreInfo));
    //sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sPicture));
    sText.Append(String.Format("rowArr[{0}] = NewRow;", iRowCounter));

    //Pageimage

    iRowCounter++;
    return sText.ToString();
}

private SPListItemCollection GetListItems(string destList, string reportsTo)
{
    SPListItemCollection ResultListItems = null;

    using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(destList);
            if (null == list)
               return ResultListItems;

            string selected = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
          // Label1.Text = selected;

            //Check if the item already exist.
            StringBuilder sCAMLQuery = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
            sCAMLQuery.Append("<Where>");
            sCAMLQuery.Append("<And>");
            if (reportsTo != string.Empty)
            {
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<Eq>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
                //sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Lookup'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");

                sCAMLQuery.Append("</Eq>");

            }
            else
            {
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<IsNull>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("</IsNull>");
            }
            sCAMLQuery.Append("<Eq>");
            sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='Kompania' />");
            //sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Lookup'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");
            sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Text'>" + selected + "</Value>");

            sCAMLQuery.Append("</Eq>");

            sCAMLQuery.Append("</And>");
            sCAMLQuery.Append("</Where>");

            SPQuery QueryResult = new SPQuery();
            QueryResult.Query = sCAMLQuery.ToString();
            ResultListItems = list.GetItems(QueryResult);
          }
        }
       return ResultListItems;          
     }              
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In here

```
private void GetNode(string reportsTo)
{
    SPListItemCollection itemCol = GetListItems(listName, reportsTo);



     foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
        {
            //create a new row
            sAllNewRows += createNewRow(item);

            //Recursion
            GetNode(item["Name"].ToString());
        }

    }
```

You should modify it to something like this

```
private void GetNode(string reportsTo)
{
    SPListItemCollection itemCol = GetListItems(listName, reportsTo);

    for(int i=0, i< 1, i++)
    {
        //create a new row
        sAllNewRows += createNewRow(itemCol[i]);

        //Recursion
        GetNode(itemCol[i]["Name"].ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: That would help in what way to solve the issue of only generating two levels?

Comment: its taking each item and creating a separate row.. limiting it to 1 will limit to creating only two rows.. did i get it wrong?

Comment: I am getting an` System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:` error how to solve it?

Comment: @AnkitKumar any idea how to get out of`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:`

Comment: You got it right, but you also need to take into account that the array might not always have even one position

Comment: @RobertLindgren Any Idea how ti solve error?

Comment: I do not want to get a few items from the list but when I open the page it shows the whole chart with its 50 item and instead whet it opens I want to display only 5 items and let user to expand others do you understand me?